# How to monitor a remote Postgresql Amazon EC2 database through Munin?

Tags: amazon-ec2, postgresql, munin, graph

How can I monitor a remote postgresql database on Amazon EC2 using Munin? I would like to graph the number of reads, writes, and total database operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `munin` and `munin-node`, configure the various `postgres_` plugins, and behold your graphs about 5 minutes later.